# Software for training and event management

Tags: windows-server

I'm looking for a software that helps me manage all our inhouse trainings and other company events. Requirements
- Plan events
- Set attendee limits
- Attendee registration
- Notifications about upcomming events

I did not find any software like that, but i'd love to have one.

Answer (score 1):

It'll depend a bit what exactly you mean by "manage". But for sure you should have a look at [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/). And specifically for anything about managing events, you may want to look at the tons of add-on modules that are available, as explained in my answer to "[Which Drupal module(s) should I use for making reservations based on availability in a calendar?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28598/which-drupal-modules-should-i-use-for-making-reservations-based-on-availabilit/28599#28599)".

Answer (score 0):

Look into Regpack - they do event management that includes what you asked - setting limits, attendee registration, email communication, and payments, reporting, etc. http://regpacks.com/events They are one of the only event software options on the market that allow you to embed the process on your event website, which is super helpful and cuts down on loss of attendees due to redirecting. They just rolled out new auto billing features as well, so setting up payment plans and other payment related tools are easy, which is helpful if your event costs money and you want to get paid on time.

You can also look at Capterra - they are a reputable site that lists many software options, reviews and features so you can easily compare. Most of the big names are on there and have intro videos and the like so you can easily view what each option has to offer. http://www.capterra.com/sem/event-management-software