# Web-Based Open Source Hostel Management system?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, information-management

Please suggest any open source Hostel Management system. features we are looking for we just need a way to keep track of the students, hostels details. Freeware is welcome but Open Source is preferred.

Comment: Have you tried googling for hotel management which I suspect is a similar use case? Here's the [top result](https://github.com/tugbadogan/hotelmanagement)

Comment: A "Hostel Management System" sound very specific. It is likely that you don't get this for free. If you use more general point of view, then you want to manage resources. Maybe there is a free tool for this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/)

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- **Full** office suite including database, spreadsheet, word processing, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't call LibreOffice a "Hostel Management system". You would pretty much have to creating one from scratch unless there are templates available.

Answer (score 0):

The question needs a bit more clarification on requirements, but there are a number of drupal-based solutions that can help with hostel management, bookings, payments, etc. like [Rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms).

But see [this previous SE answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28598/which-drupal-modules-should-i-use-for-making-reservations-based-on-availabilit) for a comprehensive list.